Getting Error: fabric-ca request enroll failed with errors [[ { code: 20, message: 'Authentication failure' } ]]
I am using the fabric-network module to connect to the the certificate authority to enroll the admin and the user. But I wanted to have custom affiliation so i made changes in the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml and fed it to the ca container by using volumes. But after doing that i am getting this error:
Error: fabric-ca request enroll failed with errors [[ { code: 20, message: 'Authentication failure' } ]]
when trying to enroll admin or any user(you can't without an admin).
The same thing is working if i dont feed the edited fabric-ca-server-config.yaml to the container, it creates the default affiliations which does not give any authentication errors.
This is my connection-profile.json
{
    "name": "EvidenceVault-Police",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Police",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Police": {
            "mspid": "PoliceMSP",
            "peers": [
                "PD100.police.evidence-vault.com",
                "PD101.police.evidence-vault.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.police.evidence-vault.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "PD100.police.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\npS8RMrpWIFut8Ph8ghYlVKDQ\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "PD100.police.evidence-vault.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "PD100.police.evidence-vault.com"
            }
        },
        "PD101.police.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\npS8RMrpWIFut8Ph8ghYlVKDQ\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "PD101.police.evidence-vault.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "PD101.police.evidence-vault.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.police.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.police.evidence-vault.com",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": ["-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\npS8RMrpWIFut8Ph8ghYlVKDQ\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"]
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}

the tlsCACerts are copied from crypto-config/peerOrganizations/police.evidence-vault.com/tlsca/tlsca.police.evidence-vault.com-cert.pem
the tls ca pem files are the same for all the peers in that organizations are the same, so i pasted the the pem everywhere in the connection profile
After encountering this error:
I took a look at the volumes of the CA and found there were two files ca.crt and tls-cert.pem files in the volume.
Tried both of them either placing them here:
"certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.police.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.police.evidence-vault.com",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": ....
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }

in the connection profile.
or
at every place in the connection profile which needed a pem.
but still got the same error:
Error: fabric-ca request enroll failed with errors [[ { code: 20, message: 'Authentication failure' } ]]
